# Accessing Keycloak endpoints

Tags: nestjs, keycloak, insomnia

**Context**

A NestJS back-end project at their beginnings with no e2e tests

As OpenID Connect Node.js adapters are deprecated, I am implementing my own Keycloak service in the NestJs app

Keycloak & mySQL database both on a Docker instance

Keycloak act as middleware protecting routes and allowing users to login

Keycloak has a dedicated realm I configured with a set of clients and users (barely no custom roles or group for now)

[image: How I use Insomnia to get token from Keycloak and then get access to routes in my app]

[image: my keycloak config]

[image: my keycloak config]

It is a necessity for me and my team to test endpoints via Postman like software, we chose Insomnia

**PROBLEM**

We have trouble accessing endpoints with token through insomnia and issues debugging due to the lack of info returned by Keycloak

[image: Insomnia screenshot]

```
keycloak-1  | 2024-03-13 09:37:16,675 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-1) type="USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR", realmId="55542514-fc71-4e4e-be3e-42af869de2a7", clientId="null", userId="null", ipAddress="172.18.0.1", error="access_denied", auth_method="validate_access_token"
```

EDIT: Try via CLI

`curl http://localhost:8080/realms/myapp/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo -H "Authorization: Bearer <mytoken>"`

It is throwing the same access denied response

Comment: You need to setup for adding user info at client scope in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792385/keycloak-openid-connect-userinfo)

Comment: Do you have any clue why my access is denied ?

Comment: Reason, you did not turn `ON` the option Add to userinfo at client scope , if not get 403 error, even if master token. Go to that link(my first comment) read @dreamcrash answer.

Comment: I actually did, shall I had some screenshots of my keycloak in my original question ?

Comment: OK, I will try when I return home.

Comment: You can update to add a picture in your question.

Comment: I put my nest-app client details and the follow up for @dreamcrash response int the other thread

Comment: OK, can you give me link your nest-app client details?

Comment: Openid scope was missing  I am going to join a circus

Comment: Good finding! Ha Ha.

Comment: Kinda, still a bit beyond my comprehension I am letting this sit a little before writing the answer

Comment: I got 403 error even if turn on add to user info. let me know if you success it.

Comment: I tested it by Keycloak version from v19 to v24.
Only v19 works, All other higher versions give 403 error.

Comment: That may be something to bring up to the keycloak forum

Comment: You can ask in Keycloak forum. Same question in forum, he using 19.0.1 in [here]
(https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/keycloak-missing-data-in-the-userinfo-response/19550). I tested v19.0.3. It also works.