# Obtain id_token with Keycloak

Tags: java, openid, keycloak

Who knows how to obtain the id_token with `Keycloak`?

I have been working with `Keycloak` in `Java` (Spring, JEE) and postman.

The basics work fine but I need the `id_token` since there are some claims that they are not present in the `access_token` but they are present in the `id_token`.

Using the `keycloak-core` library I could obtain the Keycloak context, but the id_token attribute always is null.

Some idea?

Comment: `I have been working with Keycloak in Java (Spring, JEE) and postman.`

@Pablo which Keycloak Adapter are you using?
Did you take a look at official documentation regarding [Security Context](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/3.2/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/adapter-context.html) ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I tried with Spring Adapter, Wildfly Adapter, and I tried to get the id_token through http calls, I checked in the official documentation but I could not find any regarding id_token or how to configure to get it in the `/token` response.

Comment: I guess the access token and id token are equivalent here. You can still add custom claims if you want to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32678883/keycloak-retrieve-custom-attributes-to-keycloakprincipal

Comment: Not really, the access token and id_token could not have the same information, sometimes the `id_token` is used to sensitive information and that is the requirement that I have now.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using keycloak version 3.2.1,
then below mail chain will help you.
Hi All

I am using below curl command

```
curl -k  https://IP-ADDRESS:8443/auth/realms/Test123/protocol/openid-connect/token -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -d "client_id=SURE_APP" -d "client_secret=ca3c4212-f3e8-43a4-aa14-1011c7601c67"
```

In the above command's response id_token is missing ,which is require for kong to tell who i am?

In my keycloak `realm->client-> Full Scope Allowed ->True`

Ok I found it we have to add

```
scope=openid
```

then only it will work

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped me a lot, I just added 1 think `realm->client->Service Accounts Enabled ->True`. With this I can obtain the `id_token` in token endpoint

Answer (score 12):

I had the same thing with Keycloak 3.4.3 version.

I added `scope=openid` to my request as Gal Margalit mentioned in his answer and it works.

Here is my request:

> curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d
>   **"scope=openid"** -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=test" -d "username=test@test.hr" -d "password=test"
>   'https://YOUR-DOMAIN/realms/test123/protocol/openid-connect/token'

Answer (score 4):

In keycloak 2.x the id_token was inside the returned token object.
They removed it in keycloak 3.x.
just add to your request the following:

```
scope: "openid"
```

as listed below to retain the id_token

http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2018-February/013170.html

Answer (score 0):

On `Keycloak 23.0.4` the **auth** in the URL has been left out, so for a client it is now i.e.:

```
curl -k  https://IP-ADDRESS:8443/realms/Test123/protocol/openid-connect/token -d "grant_type=client_credentials" -d "client_id=SURE_APP" -d "client_secret=ca3c4212-f3e8-43a4-aa14-1011c7601c67" -d "scope=openid"
```

To get the `id_token` for a user, the user credentials have to be added and the `grant_type` has to be changed to **password**, i.e.:

```
curl -k  https://IP-ADDRESS:8443/realms/Test123/protocol/openid-connect/token -d "grant_type=password" -d "client_id=SURE_APP" -d "client_secret=ca3c4212-f3e8-43a4-aa14-1011c7601c67" -d "scope=openid" -d "user=jdoe" -d "password=jdoe"
```