# What is the best approach to logout from keycloak after authentication via pkce?

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, logout, pkce

What is the proper way to logout?

These are the keycloak client settings:

```
Realm: REALM

Client ID:              pkce-client
Client Protocol:        openid-connect
Access Type:            public
Standard Flow Enabled:  ON
Valid Redirect URIs:    http://localhost:4200/
Backchannel Logou:      ON
```

OpenID Connect Compatibility Modes

```
Use Refresh Tokens: ON
```

Advanced Settings:

```
Proof Key for Code Exchange Code Challenge Method: S256
```

Is there a good documentation?

My idea was to delete the token on the client side, but then the session is still active in keycloak.

The solution was to call the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/REALM/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint=InR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICIxUVJwMXAtbmk1WmcyZmlyRHFoRS1iS1hwemZDaWFocGs4Zi1XRkQtRDZ3In0.eyJleHAiOjE2NDE3NjUyNjYsImlhdCI6MTY0MTc2.......
```

Comment: If keycloak uses OAuth2, chances are they have a 'revoke' endpoint. Using that endpoint you can tell the oauth2 server to expire certain tokens.

Answer (score 5):

OIDC standard (implemented by Keycloak) supports [RP initiated logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html#RPLogout). So make browser redirect (not a XMLHttpRequest request only) to `end_session_endpoint` with proper logout parameters.

BTW: `end_session_endpoint` is not the same as `revocation_endpoint`; logout != revocation.

But this is OIDC logout only (logout from the Keycloak). You may have still own app session (it depends on the app implementation), so app needs to destroy app session ("delete refresh token on the client side", ...) to have logout from the app.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to call the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/REALM/protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint=InR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICIxUVJwMXAtbmk1WmcyZmlyRHFoRS1iS1hwemZDaWFocGs4Zi1XRkQtRDZ3In0.eyJleHAiOjE2NDE3NjUyNjYsImlhdCI6MTY0MTc2.......
```

Answer (score 0):

/edit This is for non-PCKE, where access and refresh token are stored in cookie:

You can create a logout service backend that you make available on /logout endpoints of all your services.

When the service is called, it first obtains the ID token for the client used to connect:

```
curl -k  https://<keycloak-host>/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token \
  -d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
  -d "client_id=<client-id>" \
  -d "client_secret=<secret>" \
  -d "scope=openid"
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49334183).

Then it constructs a redirect URL in a format like this based on host of user:

> https://<host>?cache-buster=1445660571

With an optional cache buster.

Create a redirect URL to the authorization server in this format:

> https:///auth/realms//protocol/openid-connect/logout?id_token_hint=&post_logout_redirect_uri=<url encoded redirect URL>

Then create a response with status code 303 (See Other) with as Location the URL constructed above, and as headers you set the "kc-access", "kc-state", "OAuth_Token_Request_State" and "request_uri" cookies to expired. Clojure example:

```clj
(defn- expired-cookie [host cookie-name]
  (str cookie-name "=; "
       "domain=." host "; "
       "path=/; "
       "expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; "
       "HttpOnly"))
```

Example response:

```
status: 303
headers: 
{"Location" "https://<keycloak host>/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/logout
?id_token_hint=<id token you obtained>
&post_logout_redirect_uri=<url encoded redirect URL>"
 "Set-Cookie" 
["kc-access=; domain=.https://<domain>; path=/; 
  expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; HttpOnly"
 "kc-state=; domain=.https://<domain>; path=/; 
  expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; HttpOnly"
 "OAuth_Token_Request_State=; domain=.https://<domain>; path=/; 
  expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; HttpOnly"
 "request_uri=; domain=.https://<domain>; path=/; 
  expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT; HttpOnly"]}
```

This returned response will log the user out and redirect to the constructed redirect URL (for example, where the user came from).

This /logout endpoint can be made available as a route on all services that use Keycloak.

Comment: Your code looks good, but I have a problem: If I call the "token" url so keycloak creates a new session and the logout "without" the confirm message won't work. In the end each call to the "https://<keycloak-host>/auth/realms/<realm>/protocol/openid-connect/token" will create a new session for the user. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @Flo Are you running this code from a backend? From a frontend it won't work since you cannot delete the cookies (if they are http only).