# Keycloak API, best way to get users by a list of ids

Tags: rest, keycloak

I´m using the official [Keycloak API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/5.0/rest-api/index.html). I have a list of ids and would like to get all users represented by the ids. So let´s say i have a list with ids `1, 7, 9`. Optimally i would would want to have a GET endpoint which accepts a list/array of ids as a PathVariable. But it seems like there´s no method like this. So i think i either have to send a seperate request for each id in the list and get the according user(which would result in n requests with a list of size n) or i have to get all users and filter them afterwards. Is there no better way?

Answer (score -1):

Or as it is pointed out by @cyee in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69074230/is-there-any-way-to-get-users-by-multiple-usernameskeycloak-admin-rest-api) question, some OAUTH providers recommend having a separate database with users' info. Of course, that requires creating a separate "auth-api" which would behave as middleware (updating a user  would trigger an update of database).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).