# Is there any way to get users by multiple usernames[Keycloak Admin Rest API]

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I am new to this keycloak user management.

**Basically I want to fetch users using "IN" condition on username field**

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no. See REST API doc: https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Currently, keycloak doesn't support getting multiple users by ids or usernames.

You can use keycloak SPI:

This is my repo for this query function:
[Bulk user query](https://github.com/imcyee/keycloak-bulk-user)

If there is any bug. Feel free to submit pull request too.

Comment: how fast is this. Does keycloak's database make use of an index to query by userId/username or are you performing a full walk of the user table (linear time complexity)

Comment: It depends on how fast the query builder execute. This is the link to the code. I didn't give it any benchmark yet.

Comment: this is the main execution code: https://github.com/imcyee/keycloak-bulk-user/blob/master/providers/rest/src/main/java/org/keycloak/bulkuser/rest/BulkuserResourceProvider.java

Comment: how is keycloak database indexed? is it not designed for doing bulk user operations? e.g. find users by some specific attribute(s) without doing a full table walk.

Comment: I think it is probably a feature that is not in the priority list. I see similar functionality in Auth0. I believe they should have it indexed at least for the user id field, but i didnt check it. My usecase volume is not yet require optimization yet.