# Query custom attribute in keycloak via keycloak admin for nodejs

Tags: node.js, keycloak

I am trying to query custom attribute created in keycloak server.
example code : `keycloak.users.find({ customAttribute: 'value' })`
but I am unable to do that. It returns all the users in keycloak instead of users that match the  condition

Comment: Where you get the code how to access the customAttribute ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve Custom Attribute from JavaScript (using Javascript Adapter) Keycloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53224680/retrieve-custom-attribute-from-javascript-using-javascript-adapter-keycloak)

Comment: Thanks for help but it doesn't answer my question. I can fetch custom attributes but I want to fetch users based on that attribute like we query users with firstname and lastname in keycloak. For instance I want to fetch users from keycloak that meet certain criteria from custom attribute. Suppose that attribute name is  `custom` and I want to fetch users that are having value `abc` for this custom attribute. 
I got the code from `https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-admin-client/blob/main/test/users.spec.ts` they have a test case for custom attribute

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.