# Keycloak client role attribute array

Tags: arrays, keycloak, roles, keycloak-rest-api

**Situation**

I have a keycloak server (v12.0.2) running with a client that has some roles. I can add custom attributes to that roles and retrieve them. No problem. But the roles always return an array.

entering key "foo" and value "bar" gives me

```json
 "attributes": {
    "foo": [
      "bar"
    ]
  }
```

**What I would like to have**

I would like to have multiple entries in the array. To stay in the previous example, I would like to have "bar" and "baz".

```json
 "attributes": {
    "foo": [
      "bar",
      "baz"
    ]
  }
```

**What I have tried**

- Simply adding 2 entries with the same key - that just leads to overwriting the first entry with the second. So I get

```json
 "attributes": {
    "foo": [
      "baz"
    ]
  }
```

- Supplying an array index in the key ("foo[0]" = "bar" and "foo[1]" = "baz" is just two different keys and giving me

```json
  "attributes": {
    "foo[0]": [
      "bar"
    ],
    "foo[1]": [
      "baz"
    ]
  }
```

- Separating the values with semicolon, space or comma returns

```json
  "attributes": {
    "foo": [
      "bar,baz"
    ]
  }
```

(and the same with ";" or " " respectively)

Is there any way to do that or do I have to go with custom defined separators and split the string in my application (which is not a problem, but I think getting the values as an array would be better)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `##` as a delimiter, example: `bar##baz` . But with this delimiter the order of the array is not guaranteed , though you save the data as `bar##baz` the array may return as `foo[0]= "baz"` and `foo[1] as="bar"`.

If the order is not important you can try this delimiter.

Comment: Thank you very much! The order does indeed not matter for me. May I ask if you found that in the documentation and I was just too blind to see it?

Comment: @MCMLXXXII , It's not part of the documentation, You can refer this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60767085/keycloak-map-multiple-user-attributes/64008332#64008332

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the similar issue and tried with different steps

1. Protocol mapper `multivalued` is True and the attribute value `"foo"##"bar"`, this works and output as ["foo", "bar"]
2. both `foo##bar` and `"foo##bar"`  didn't work for me and produces error in admin console evaluate user

Now to use option 1 with Rest API payload is not possible because it comes with invalid json, so make it work using a workaround, Turn off `multivalued` option in protocol mapper

Rest API Payload for the same looks like

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "somekey": "[\"foo\", \"bar\"]"
  }
}
```

Only issue will comes when you retrieve the user info it will look like this

```
"somekey": [
    "[\"foo\", \"bar\"]"
]
```

with javascript you can parse the array and do operation

if someone find other useful solution please share